# JavaScript form validation "value" not being passed from form onsubmit event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a form that uses jQuery autocomplete to populate an input. To prevent a user from typing the first couple of letters and then tabbing to the next input assuming that the field is complete, I am incorporating a JS form validation that compares the input against an array. The comparison works fine, but for some reason, the input field value `colltown_name` is not passed to the form validation. However other input fields are.

I have created a test environment, that on error, displays what was submitted on the `colltown_name` input.

```
var x = document.forms["quoteRequest"]["colltown_name"].value; //returns: "Localhost says " , so it is receiving nothing

var x = document.forms["quoteRequest"]["colltown_name"].name; //returns: "Localhost says colltown_name "
```

I cannot understand why value returns nothing to validation, but name returns the name value
If I inspect the form submission on Google Chrome, bypassing the validation, the `colltown_name.value` is submitted.
Below are snippets of my form and validation:-

```js
//var x = document.forms["quoteRequest"]["descr_goods"].value; //returns value "Goods"
//var x = document.forms["quoteRequest"]["colltown_name"].name; //returns name "colltown_name"
var x = document.forms["quoteRequest"]["colltown_name"].value;  //returns nothing
var arr=["AANDRUS, Bloemfontein", "AANHOU WEN, Stellenbosch", "ABBOTSDALE, Western Cape"];

function quoteValid()      //ADDED BY ADIEB                              
{ 
    if ($.inArray(x, arr) == -1)
    {
        alert(x);
        return false;
    }
    }
```

```html
<form name="quoteRequest" action="index.php?route=product/product" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return quoteValid()">
<div class="ui-widget">
  <input type="text" id="ctags" class="form-control col-md-8" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Start typing Collection Town" name="colltown_name">
    <input id="ctag" type="hidden" name="colltown">
                </div>
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" id="desc" name="descr_goods" value="Goods" required>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but does any of the code here help at all?  http://jsfiddle.net/natelegakis/ruwgoe95/  I'm guessing that prevenDefault and/or .focus might help.  Or, maybe this could be used somewhere in your code. if ( e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.TAB)  Take a look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/uymYJ/8/

Comment: The question is really that when the , "onsubmit event is invoked, the value of colltown_name is not being passed onto the validate function", so it cannot then evaluate if the input is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `colltown_name` value seems to be defined only once when your page is loaded. So the value of `x` is `undefined` when you pass it to the `quoteValid` function on form submit, failing the validation.

You'll have to get the updated field's value when submitting:

```
function quoteValid()  {
    var x = document.forms['quoteRequest']['colltown_name'].value;
    if ($.inArray(x, arr) == -1) {
        alert(x);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: var x = document.forms["quoteRequest"]["descr_goods"].value; //returns value "Goods" onsubmit. colltown_name has no value when the page is loaded, the user then enters info and submits, but returns no value?

Comment: You'll have to get the updated field's value when submitting: - Not sure how one would do that?

Comment: 1. That's because the value "Goods" is hard coded in your form.

2. Copy var x = document.forms['quoteRequest']['colltown_name'].value; into the quoteValid() function as I did above.

Comment: Thanks TimonNetherlands - it works and I have learnt something today...